# Odd socket behaviour under Mono 3.2.8 on Debian

Tags: vb.net, sockets, mono

I'm writing a VB.Net app in VS2015 which connects to a socket and listens for data.  It works perfectly on Windows but when I try to run it under Mono 3.2.8 I get an unusual behaviour.

Here is a simplified version of my code.  This works on Windows:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        ' Declare client socket and client stream to get data from the dongle etc
        Dim clientSocket As New TcpClient()
        Dim clientStream As NetworkStream

        ' Connect to socket
        clientSocket.ExclusiveAddressUse = False
        clientSocket.LingerState.LingerTime = 0

        ' Try to connect to socket
        Try
            clientSocket.Connect("127.0.0.1", 30003)
        Catch ex As Exception
            ' write error
            Console.WriteLine("Exception: " & ex.ToString())
        End Try

        ' Tie server stream to socket
        clientStream = clientSocket.GetStream()

    End Sub

End Module
```

The error message thrown is:

Unhandled Exception:
System.InvalidOperationException: Bind has already been called for this socket
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.set_ExclusiveAddressUse (Boolean value) [0x00000] in :0
  at System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.set_ExclusiveAddressUse (Boolean value) [0x00000] in :0
  at ConsoleApplication1.Module1.Main () [0x00000] in :0
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.InvalidOperationException: Bind has already been called for this socket
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.set_ExclusiveAddressUse (Boolean value) [0x00000] in :0
  at System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.set_ExclusiveAddressUse (Boolean value) [0x00000] in :0
  at ConsoleApplication1.Module1.Main () [0x00000] in :0

As I'm setting clientSocket.ExclusiveAddressUse = False before I specify the IP address and port I can't see why it's failing.

Looking around on the web I can see mentions of this as a bug back in 2010 but nothing more recent.  I've searched the release notes of all releases after 3.2.8 but there is no mention so it looks like this is still a bug ?

If it is, is there a work around ?

Comment: mono 3.x is very old, please test with mono 4.2.x (or newer) first

Comment: That's true but it's the default version that ships on the Raspberry Pi which is the platform that my app will be rolled out on.  Updating to the latest version of Mono following the guide here: http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/#debian-ubuntu-and-derivatives results in an illegal instruction on my Pi 2.  I'll try it on my Pi 3 ...

Comment: post the problem you have about installing the new Mono as a separate stackoverflow question please

Comment: The socket bind error is not version related.  Mono 4.6.2 on an RPi3 still throws the same error message ("System.InvalidOperationException: Bind has already been called for this socket at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.set_ExclusiveAddressUse (System.Boolean value) [0x00011] in <bd46d4d4f7964dfa9beea098499ab597>:0") as above so it would appear to be a bug.  Hopefully there's a workaround ...

Comment: ok cool then update your question to state that it happens in a newer version of Mono

Comment: BTW if you're going to report the bug I recommend you to attach C# version of the testcase instead of VB.NET, you will have more chances to get it looked at ;)